# A Spring boot application fails to `Autowire` a Service class that is proxied as a new Thread

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-aop

I am using `Spring Boot` [v. 2.1.4.RELEASE] and the `@Async` annotation along with `CompletableFuture` in order to implement asynchronous and non blocking calls.

I have implemented an Config class for running a `TaskExecutor` that will provide the multi-threading environment, as well as pair of Service-Controller classes that implement a POST request.

#### Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {  
    @Bean(name = "musterExecutor")
    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AppExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    }
}
```

A service class where `Status` is a pojo used for mapping the response.

#### Service

```
@Service
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MusterService<T> {
    private static final String request_status = RestURIConstants.STATUS;
    private static final String request_execution = RestURIConstants.EXECUTE;
    private static final String request_async = Constants.ASYNC;
    private static final String DATA_FUSION = Constants.DATA_FUSION;

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Async("musterExecutor")
public CompletableFuture<Status> execute(Payload payload) {
    HttpHeaders headers = setHeaders();
    String input = Constructor.createPayload(payload);
    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(input, headers);
    Status s = restTemplate.postForObject(execution_url, request_execution, Status.class);

    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(s);
}

@Async("musterExecutor")
public CompletableFuture<Status[]> getStatus() {
    log.debug("Sending Status Request");

    final String status_url = request_status;
    HttpHeaders headers = setHeaders();
    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(request_async, headers);
    Status[] s = restTemplate.postForObject(status_url, requestEntity, Status[].class);

    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(s);
}

private HttpHeaders setHeaders() {
    // code for setting the Headers
    return headers;
}
```

}

Along with a simple

#### Service interface

```
public interface GenericService<T> {

    public abstract CompletableFuture<Status[]> getStatus();

    public abstract CompletableFuture<Status> execute(Payload payload);

}
```

#### Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api")
public class MusterController {

    @Autowired
    private MusterService<Status> musterService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/status", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public CompletableFuture<Status[]> status() {
        CompletableFuture<Status[]> cf_status = new CompletableFuture<Status[]>();
        try {
            cf_status = musterService.getStatus();
            return cf_status;
        } catch (RestClientException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return cf_status;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/execute", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public CompletableFuture<Status> execute(@RequestBody Payload payload) throws SchedulerException, IOException {
        CompletableFuture<Status> cf_execution_body = new CompletableFuture<Status>();
        Status execution_body = new Status();
        try {
            cf_execution_body = musterService.execute(payload);
            execution_body = cf_execution_body.get();
            return cf_execution_body;
        } catch (RestClientException e) {
            log.error("RestClientException:{} \t Cause:{}", e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cf_execution_body;
    }

}
```

The instance of the class is correctly proxied in order to launch the thread, but when i try to `implement` the Service class with the interface class (aka. `public class MusterService<T> implements GenericService<T>`..) it gives me the following error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException
>   The service is proxied as a new Thread and for some reason cannot be
>   Autowired

When i remove the `implements` then everything works as expected.

*NOTE:* I've put the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)`  annotation in order to make it work as suggested but it doesn't do anything. How can i make it work?

#### Stackoverflow references:

- [BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException due to autowired fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509142/beannotofrequiredtypeexception-due-to-autowired-fields)
- [Original interface is lost in Spring AOP introduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089642/original-interface-is-lost-in-spring-aop-introduction)

Answer (score 4):

It's `@EnableAsync` that's causing `MusterService` to be proxied so that its `@Async` methods can be asynchronous. By default, `@EnableAsync` will create JDK proxies if the class being proxied implements a single interface. This is the case for `MusterService` when it implements `GenericService`. As a result the muster service bean has to be consumed as a `GenericService` as that's the contract that the proxy conforms to.

If you want your controller to be able to inject a `MusterService` instance you should modify `@EnableAsync` to use CGLib proxies:

```
@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

Comment: I am aware that Java classes are "proxified" but i think its Spring that doesnt understand when i want to pass a class that implements an interface. 
I've tried  > @EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true) 
but it is still the same  :/